# How to mark a repository as fork in GitHub after migrating to GitHub?

Tags: github, git-fork

I have a `main` repository and a `fork` repository managed in a GitHub-like SCM system.
Now I've migrated both repositories to GitHub by creating two repos `main` and `fork` in GitHub, added them as remotes to my local repos and pushed the entire history to both of them. So far, so good.

When I would have forked `fork` from `main` directly on GitHub `fork` would be marked as such on the GitHub UI.

[image: example screenshot]

My question is, can I *connect* the repositories in GitHub somehow such that they appear as if forked on GitHub?

Comment: Open a support ticket with GitHub: Go to [https://support.github.com/request/fork](https://support.github.com/request/fork), select "Attach a fork" and describe which repos should be attacked how.